# Dnd-kit: active item loses order when dragged on Droppable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, dnd-kit

I'm facing a problem using @dnd-kit.
The soring part works well (for example when I start dragging 1st element it obvioeulsy does sort), but when I reach a droppable element (green Thrash), the sorting breaks and the 1st element goes back.

You can see live demo here: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dndkit-grid-with-drag-handle-example-forked-klio8?file=/src/App.js)

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was in handlers. When a dragged item reaches outside of the original drop area (a list), there is no more `over`-item under it. This is when the `dragOver` handler used to crash, since it relies on `over.id` internally

Solution:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dndkit-grid-with-drag-handle-example-forked-w4j3sn

1. Added checks for null and for id match
2. Moved deletion logic to `dragEnd` handler
3. Added state for dragged item reaching trash, so that list item can reflect it (becomes hidden)
4. List item is hidden when dragged + new prop is true
5. Moved Trash component out of original one, not critical tho